# Should I implement IEquatable, or IComparable?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class. The *thing* that this class is meant to represent is such that we may speak about such *things* being equal to each other, and we may also come up with a scheme to rank them for purposes of comparison.

However, it so happens that it is rare that one feels the need to rank these *things*, but one often needs to check if two such *things* are equal.

So, I can implement both `IEquatable` for my class as well as `IComparable`. While `IComparable` provides some extra functionality, it is very unlikely that anyone will care about this extra functionality. Neither one seemingly provides a clear advantage, either logically or functionality-wise.

Which interface should I implement, `IEquatable`, `IComparable`, or both? Why? (I am specifically wondering about framework-wide implications either interface)

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410101/whats-the-difference-between-icomparable-iequatable-interfaces?rq=1) is similar, but the answers only state the obvious, which doesn't help me.

In case you are wondering, the class is meant to represent a nucleotide. Nucleotides can readily be equated, but they can also be compared (eg. alphabetically).

Comment: Is there ever a possibility that you'd need to sort them?  I know you said that it's unlikely, but if you were to give the class to someone else can you think of a reason they'd ever need to sort?

Comment: I'm certain that it's possible to come up with a contrived scenario in which one might need to alphabetically sort them (for producing human-readable output with nice formatting) or perhaps sort them by some biochemical property (like mass). But it would be contrived, and if I were to implement `IComparable`, I would have to write documentation (without it the method would be useless) for methods that would very rarely be used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would definitely implement `IEquatable<T>` but skip `IComparable`/`IComparable<T>` for now.

As you said there is no one way to compare nucleotides. Someone may need to compare them alphabetically, someone may need another way to sort them. I would rather provide different implementations of [`IComparer<Nucleotide>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to implement `IComparable`/`IComparable<T>` itself.

Comment: There is no non-generic `IEquatable`, as if there was it would just match the `Equals()` override all objects have. That said, one must always override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` appropriately when one does implement `IEquatable<T>`, so your point holds.

Answer (score 3):

It is primarily opinion based but I would not implement `IComparable` if comparability is not obvious (like in number). If someone would like to sort Nucleotides, for example, it can provide its own `IComparer` implementation. As a library author I would provide a set of possible `IComparer`s, for example to sort them alphabetically as you said.

Answer (score 3):

If the objects are inherently comparable then I would do the extra work and implement `IComparable<T>` on top of `IEquatable<T>`.  As the author of the type you are in the best position to provide the correct implementation.  Leaving it to another developer to implement increases the chance of the following happen

- Them implementing comparison incorrectly.  Other developers will likely be less familiar with the data than you and hence more likely to miss corner cases
- Duplicate cadoe.  If you don't provide the defacto comparison then every developer will separately have to do it themselves leading to duplicate code

Comment: If other developers each implement their own comparison, then communication at that organization is pretty poor :-/

Comment: @MattGreer whose to say they work at the same company?  Perhaps this code becomes more widely used and you have developers at diff companies using it

Comment: @MattGreer To be sure, in my particular case, the other developers are (if any) "me in the distant future".

Comment: @MattGreer "then communication at that organization is pretty poor". In other words, a typical organization. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the interface that gives you what you need now. If you later find that `IComparable` is something you need, implement it then.

It can be tough to decide how much future proofing to do. But when adding the additional future feature is relatively simple, I always opt to not do them. You may find you never need `IComparable`, and even if it's a tiny addition, it still requires maintenance and consideration.

Comment: More to the point, `IComparable` before it's clear how it's needed is anti-future-proofing, because if a later requirement for a given means of comparison doesn't match it, it would be a breaking change to change the current implementation.